# How to show python information when Mouseover in Blender 2.8?

Tags: scripting

How to show python information when **Mouseover** in Blender 2.8?

*Blender 2.7x*

[image]

*Blender 2.8x*

[image]

Comment: system preferences> Interface> enable python tooltips

Comment: @susu Cool. It's exactly what I need:)